# How can I use macro as one of other macro parameters list

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Here is a dummy example:

```
#define DEFINE_STRUCTURE(Result, Structure, a, b, c)  int a;
#define MEMBER_INT(name, width)                       Int, name, width
```

When I'm doing

```
DEFINE_STRUCTURE(Result, Structure,  MEMBER_INT(b, c))
```

I get this warning:

> warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'DEFINE_STRUCTURE'

but I expect it to expand to

```
DEFINE_STRUCTURE(Result, Structure,  Int, b, c)
```

How could I define the macros to achieve that?

Comment: It will be easier if you can state, what are you trying to achieve ? Here in question, it's difficult to understand what is the role of the params other than `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add one more step to the substitution process.

```
#define DEFINE_STRUCTURE(Result, Structure, a, b, c)  int a;
#define MEMBER_INT(name, width)                       Int, name, width

#define DEFINE_STRUCTURE2(Result, Structure, x) DEFINE_STRUCTURE(Result, Structure, x)
DEFINE_STRUCTURE2(Result, Structure,  MEMBER_INT(b, c))
```

Remember: on an invocation of a function-like macro, arguments are identified, then each argument is separately evaluated, then the parameters are substituted by the results of the evaluation.

Comment: Hi Avakar, same warning: "warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'DEFINE_STRUCTURE'" --> Any other idea?