# How can I call put macro inside another macro agrument list?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use macro as one of other macro parameters list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153811/how-can-i-use-macro-as-one-of-other-macro-parameters-list)

```
#define SUM(a, b, c)  (a+b+c)
#define DUPLICATE(a)   a, a

int result = SUM(1, DUPLICATE(2)); // equivalent to SUM(1, 2, 2)
```

I get this warning:

```
warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'SUM'
```

How can I avoid this warning and make `SUM(1, DUPLICATE(2))` expand to `SUM(1, 2, 2)`?

Comment: @Andrey The question you link to was asked by OP 5 hours ago, so why is he again asking?

Comment: @halex: Because that question was closed

Comment: Answer to the linked question is applicable here

Comment: @Andrey I think you are right. He persists :)

Comment: Maybe DUPLICATE itself is not a good idea.

Comment: GCC is intolerant to this kind of macro expansion (it produces error), so if you want to make your code portable, avoid macros like DUPLICATE.

Comment: here is the link to the original post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158998/how-can-i-call-put-macro-inside-another-macro-agrument-list

Comment: the answer given in the original post was still with "not enough actual parameters" warning

Comment: @bochaltura: Then why did you accept it? If that answer is wrong then you should say so in a comment and wait for more answers rather than repost the question.